# Prime number checker always returns true

Tags: ruby

I'm been given an assignment to create a method that takes an integer and returns `true` if it is prime and `false` if it is not. The code I wrote below is not returning `false` for non-prime numbers. Any ideas?

```
def prime?(integer)
  (2...integer).each do |divisor| 
    if integer % divisor == 0
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `else` condition kicks in immediately if it is not divisible by any divisor. You need to move it outside the loop.

```
def prime? (integer)
  (2...integer).each do |divisor| 
    if integer % divisor == 0
     return false
    end
  end
  true
end
```

One-liner with `none?` (thanks sawa)

```
(2...integer).none? {|i| integer % i == 0}
```

Comment: Your suggestion is right. You can simplify the code using `none?`.

Comment: Oooh, I wasn't aware of `none?`. Thanks.